# Clicking a link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something pretty basic, but am struggling.

```
a = 'www.someURL.com'
```

I've tried a few things. I've tried to wrap it in jQuery

```
$(a).click()

Uncaught 
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$(a)` you defined `a` as a string, it is not a jquery element. Unless you defined `www` as a custom html element and it has class `.someURL` and `.com`

Comment: You're trying to click a string. That's not going to work.

Comment: @ceejayoz "click a string" itself sounds funny :D

Comment: also, click() takes a function as an argument

Comment: @steven35 It doesn't have to. Without an argument, it **triggers** a click.

Comment: It is `"Unclear what you are asking"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That's not a link
2. This would be a link: `a = '<a href="http://www.someURL.com">link</a>'; link = $(a);`
3. But you probably don't need to click a link.

If you're just trying to load a new address:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.someURL.com';
```

will do just fine. No jQuery needed.

Comment: Crocodile Dundee: "That's not a link... now this, this is a link" :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$(a).click(function() {
 window.location.href(a)
})
```

but "a" must be something clickable in your page.